# Moving git tracking into a subdirectory without tracking siblings

Tags: git

Can anyone guide me on how to move a git directory into a subdirectory?

The current directory structure is as follows:

```
/bigproject
  --.git
  --partA/
  --partB/
```

I want to make it like:

```
/bigproject
  --partA/
    --.git
  --partB/
```

I do not care about the history of partB, I will make a new git directory in there. I do want the history for partA kept when I move it into the partA directory.

How would I accomplish this? This guide tries to accomplish something similar but different: [Detach (move) subdirectory into separate Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository)

Comment: What is wrong with the answer you posted along with your question? This seems to solve your exact problem.

Comment: Thats more concerned with splitting directories and keeping things. Perhaps git-paranoia was getting to me.

Comment: I don't really understand your question then. It sounds like you want to split directories and keep things. Anyway, looks like you found your answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git rm -r partB
git mv partA/* .
git commit
```

... and you're done.

This keeps all your *previous* history (you could rewrite it with `git filter-branch` to get rid of `partB`'s history and the `partA` grand rename if you wish) but makes the current `partA` directory be the new top of the repository.

Comment: Is there an issue with this and ignored files? I'm getting fatal: not under version control, source=bp-site/manage.pyc, destination=manage.pyc

Comment: @NoviceCoding Yes. You can remove ignored files from `partA` using git's `clean` command, or move them the old-fashioned way.